# How to find location of Global variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables

there is a site I'm working on has one Global variable 'Overlay' I don't seem to find where it is declared. We have multiple external JS files which are actually using that Variable but I just don't seem to find where it is declared itself. I can see its appearing in the console when I type it though. Could someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Search your project for '''Overlay ='''?

Comment: Personally I search at the server level .. It's fast once you're used to doing it.  --  Something like `grep 'Overlay'` or `grep 'window.Overlay'` at command line --  This will give you every instance when `Overlay` is used.  --  Including file name and line number.

Comment: Use `Ctrl+F` in the devtools, it should show you all the source locations that mention the variable.

Comment: Put `Object.defineProperty(window, "Overlay", {set(){ debugger; }});` at the top and wait for the setter to get triggered

Comment: @Bergi but I don't know which file contains this variable. there are dozens of the file. I tried CTRL + F but the variable doesn't seem to exist in any of those so far. now trying the second method you mentioned. shall I just put the line in the console to execute?

Comment: just tried.. getting the following error https://snag.gy/Jzupw6.jpg

Comment: Don't just paste that into your console; it's not going to be very useful if it runs after Overlay is already set :p

Comment: @Sab Oh, I just found that it's `Ctrl + Shift + F` to search *all files* in the devtools. Also available in their kebab icon menu.

Comment: @Bergi many thanks for the useful tip.